# Updating relational data in Hazelcast

Tags: java, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

Lets say I have the following objects:

```
Bar bar = new Bar();
bar.setX(3);
Foo foo = new Foo();
foo.setY(4);
foo.setBar(bar);

hzFooMap.put(1, foo);
hzBarMap.put(1, bar);
```

With the above code, Hazelcast will loose the relationship between foo and bar.  As in, if I update bar, then foo will not be updated as well like so:

```
Bar sameBar = hzBarMap.get(1);
sameBar.setX(20);
hzBarMap.put(1, sameBar);
Foo sameFoo = hzFooMap.get(1);
```

in the above example, sameFoo.bar.x was never updated with the new value of 20.  Is there a way in Hazelcast to have every instance updated?

I could write my own engine that remembers where everything is stored and updates EVERY instance of every object I find, but this would make writes too expensive.

Or I could somehow make pointers between maps, but this would slow down reads...  Any help on solving this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hazelcast is not a relational database. You have to rethink the way you consume your data.

As accessing object in an IMap is relatively cheap, you can try to have one map by objects types, and store a key in the dependencies instead of the target object. Or use some kind of "smart pointer" which automatically resolve this key.

But afaik Hazelcast doesn't have anything to manage relation between objects. If you really rely on this kind of properties, then maybe Hazelcast is not adapted for you.

Comment: Does HZ allow recursive calls to map.get()? For instance, if I tried to do some sort of super pointer, I would need to piece the object back together before I return from map.get(...).  I have tried this in the past a got threadstateexcepton errors due to a single thread trying to access multiple partitions